# External USB 2.0 hard drive asking me to reformat

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, formatting

Had a power loss yesterday, but the external hard drive are connected to UPS.

Today when I turn on computer and click on this drive in my computer, it's asking me to format this drive before use, but I have over 3TB of data on this drive, don't want to format, Is there a way to bring it back to life?

I'm running windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hard drive might have errors due to the power loss, 
Run the cmd command `chkdsk e: /f`
(assuming that e is the drive letter listed in 'My computer')

If that doesn't fix it then try hooking it onto another OS, preferably Linux OS

Answer (score 0):

If the file table was corrupted you would not see any files on it directly. I am pretty sure most of tour data are kept on the disk. This is because it is physically has not been erased. If so, it can be restored. You will need to run a specific recovery software. It searches for the chains of data which are supposed to be the same file(s). I mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483584/recover-data-from-formatted-lvm-luks-ext3-after-ubuntu-installed-over-it/486255#486255) a few programs for this.